# How do Raman pulses, transitions and diffraction processes work?

Tags: optics

I want to know how Raman pulses work. Also, can someone explain to me Raman transitions and Raman diffraction processes?

Additionally, how does phase get accumulated in the free evolution of any hyper-fine states in an atom?

Answer (score 1):

Well the conventional lasers rely on electronic transitions for amplification of light. The Raman lasers on the other hand make use of Raman scattering for light amplification. Raman lasers are optically pumped systems. This pumping does not produce an inversion of our photon group as in electronically stimulated lasers. Also, take a look at Stokes photons. It might help.